# Android Studio: GC overhead limit exceeded

Tags: android, android-studio

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithDexForDebug'.
> java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded
```

Tried:

```
dexOptions {
    javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
}
```

That seems to be the only solution available online.

But still it exceeds the limit on 2nd build, unless I kill the studio task and restart, which makes it work for the 1st time.

Definitely not many dependencies in the build.gradle

**build.grade**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.xxxxx.android"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 8
        versionName "1.3"
    }

    dexOptions {
        javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:6.1.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:2.3.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp-urlconnection:2.3.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit:retrofit:1.9.0'
    compile 'de.greenrobot:eventbus:2.4.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:+'
}
```

Comment: Can you show full `build.gradle`?

Comment: By increasing, java heap size will resolve this issue if that's also not enough then check https://readyandroid.wordpress.com/2020/05/02/gc-overhead-limit-exceeded-android-studio/

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Increase the IDE memory (file studio.vmoptions)

http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/configuration

My settings:

```
-Xms256m
-Xmx3080m
-XX:MaxPermSize=350m
-XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize=225m
-XX:+UseCompressedOops
```

Answer (score 40):

This is a problem of not enough java heap for gradle, not IDE

I increased Java Heap in gradle.properties

```
org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xms1024m -Xmx4096m
```

Answer (score 1):

If anyone still facing the issue and there is no impact on increasing the `IDE` memory and `gradle.properties` than `invalidate cache/restart` is the last option for you. In my case it is working after `invalidate cache/restart`

Comment: same issue. have to invlidate/restart periodically. Any other solution?

Comment: No, I found this issue two times after invalidate cache/restart it was working fine.

Comment: The problem is i have to restart/ invalidate  after 3-4 builds, periodically or it just doesnt build, uses up 100 cpu and 8gb of ram. Not really a solution for me

Comment: invalidate cache/restart takes too long. My workaround for this is to kill jdk processes on task manager and make a clean build before rebuild. Hope it helps someone that face this issue.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be connected with this bug https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=199619

Answer (score 0):

If somebody faces this issue in the future, and can't increase the IDE memory, there is another option, you need to go to your android folder and there you will find a dump file that will be likely more than 400mb, delete that file and try again. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Increasing the IDE memory help as long as there is available memory on device, and invalidate cache/restart takes too long. My workaround for this is to kill jdk processes on task manager and make a clean build before rebuild. Hope it helps someone that face this issue.

Answer (score 0):

While most of the answers involve increasing of the heap memory and are correct. In case you just check-ed out the project (and can't even synchronise the gradle) the adjustment of gradle properties can also be done via the Android studio Preferences (Settings) by navigating to the following locations:

- mac: Android Studio / Preferences / Appearance & Behavior / Memory Settings
- windows: Android Studio / File / Settings / Appearance & Behavior / Memory Settings

Once you are in the correct settings i suggest you set the:

- IDE max heap size: 2048 MB
- Gradle daemon max heap size: 2048 MB
- kOTLIN daemon max heap size: 2048 MB

Check the picture below:
[image]