# java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded

Tags: android, android-studio-3.0

Using `Android Studio 3.0 Beta 6.` This error is happening more and more, when I try build my project:

> Error:Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
>   java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded

I have tried to fix it using this SO answer: 
[Android Studio: GC overhead limit exceeded](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35034830/android-studio-gc-overhead-limit-exceeded)

However it has made no difference. The only way to fix it, is a reboot of my MBP and then all is fine for the next few builds, until it resurfaces again.

Any ideas how to fix this?

Comment: Have you increased javaMaxHeapSize ?

Comment: try to add memory to studio's heap

Comment: Will try it out and see if it solves it. Thanks guys

Comment: Happens to me every once in a while. I rebuild the project or clear the cache, then it's gone.

Comment: @Christine how do you clear the cache?

Comment: What's it called in Android Studio and Intellij, it's "invalidate caches and restart". It shouldn't be necessary, I find it sometimes helps.

Comment: Thats a temp which which works for me for now. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

I was facing the same issue and it is resolved by adding following codes, Add this to your `build.gradle` file:

```
dexOptions { 
          incremental true 
          javaMaxHeapSize "4g" 
}
```

Comment: When I add it, I get this warning: 
Warning:The `android.dexOptions.incremental` property is deprecated and it has no effect on the build process.

Comment: Remove incremental true and sync your gradle again.

Comment: Thanks. I am not sure if this fixes the issue. Let me give it some time and see if the build error comes back or not. I've upvoted for now.

Comment: If it does help you then you can mark it as a answer so it would be easy for others to resolve their query. Thanks.

Comment: Just got the error again - seems it hasn't solved the issue. Any other ideas?